# GuavaCache invalidateAll() vs setting the variable to null

Tags: java, guava

In a java application, I'm trying to invalidate all the entries of a guava cache at the end of every hour (based on system time). To do this, I know about guavaCache's invalidateAll() method. I'm contemplating on whether to use the invalidateAll() method or set the cache variable to null and allow GC to clean up the heap. Which is better? What are the pros / cons of each approach?

My goal is to ensure that the invalidated entries are purged out of the memory as quickly as possible due to memory constraints in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the approach you're describing, there's probably little benefit in using a Guava cache, and you might as well be using a `HashMap`.

It's likely better to correctly configure your cache's eviction strategy, e.g. by automatically removing entries that are older than one hour, or limiting the cache in size.

Read the chapter on [eviction](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) for specifics.

Comment: Thanks! I like your simple approach. I guess when we started with the application we did have a need for guava caching features (timed-eviction), but now, as we decided to purge data by the wall-clock, hash map should be good enough to do the job.